# is there a way to make both the mousemove and mousedown work on a canvas element in vuejs?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I have a canvas element which I have bound my listeners namely `mousemove` and `mousedown`. When I use them together only the mousemove is working and mousedown is not working but when I use mousedown alone its firing up without a problem. Anything I am missing or anything preventing the mousedown from firing up? Below is my code:

### `<template>`

```html
  <div>
    <canvas
      ref="canvasRef"
      @mousemove="handleHoverListener"
      @mousedown="mousedownListener"
      :width="WIDTH"
      :height="HEIGHT"
    ></canvas>
  </div>
```

### `<script lang="ts">`

```
import { IonButtons } from "@ionic/vue"
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch, PropType } from "vue"
import { GraphTables } from "@/interfaces/GraphTables"
import { Movable } from "@/classes/Movable"
import { Graph } from "@/classes/Graph"
import { Edge } from "@/interfaces/Edge"
import { Variable } from "@/interfaces/Variable"
import { TableVariable } from "@/interfaces/TableVariable"
import GetDataDic from "@/composables/getDataDic"
//import variableModal from "@/components/VariableModal.vue";

let HEIGHT = 0
let WIDTH = 0
let MOUSEX: number
let MOUSEY: number
const DELTA = 10
let LAST_POS = [0, 0]
let ctx: any
const isModalOpen = false
const singleTableData: any = ref<Variable>()
const singleVariable: any = ref<Variable>()
const variableModal = ref<boolean>(false)
const moreInfoModal = ref<boolean>(false)
const tblName = ref<string>("")

export default defineComponent({
  name: "CanvasComp",
  props: {
    jsonData: {
      type: Object as PropType<GraphTables[]>,
      required: true
    },
    allEdges: {
      type: Object as PropType<Edge[]>,
      required: true
    }
  },
  components: {
    IonButtons
  },
  methods: {
    mousedownListener(event: any) {
      MOUSEX = event.x
      MOUSEY = event.y

      const deltaX = Math.abs(MOUSEX - LAST_POS[0])
      const deltaY = Math.abs(MOUSEY - LAST_POS[1])
      if (deltaX >= DELTA || deltaY >= DELTA) {
        LAST_POS = [MOUSEX, MOUSEY]
        for (const e in Movable.graph.edges) {
          Movable.graph.edges[e].resetCurrDefaults()
        }

        for (const i in Movable.graph.tables) {
          //console.log(Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[0] +" ndi "+ Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[1]);
          const xDiff = Math.abs(Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[0] - MOUSEX)
          const yDiff = Math.abs(Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[1] - MOUSEY)
          // console.log(MOUSEX +" | "+ MOUSEY);
          // console.log("Table: " + Movable.graph.tables[i].name + " xDiff: " + xDiff + ", yDiff: " + yDiff);
          // check if mouse is within bufferzone
          if (
            xDiff < Movable.graph.bufferZone &&
            yDiff < Movable.graph.bufferZone
          ) {
            // check if was hovering in previous state
            // if true, then change nothing and break the loop
            if (Movable.graph.isHovering) {
              break
            }
            Movable.graph.isHovering = true
            //console.log(Movable.graph.tables[i]);
            variableModal.value = true

            //Putting the table data to TableVariable interface for easier access
            const selectedTableData = ref<TableVariable>(
              Movable.graph.tables[i]
            )
            singleTableData.value = selectedTableData.value.var
            tblName.value = Movable.graph.tables[i].name
            //console.log(singleTableData.value.var);

            Movable.graph.tables[i].highlight()
            //console.log(Movable.graph.tables[i]);

            break
          } else {
            Movable.graph.tables[i].resetDefaults()
            Movable.graph.isHovering = false
          }
        }
        Movable.c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth)
        Movable.graph.drawCanvas()
      }
    },

    handleHoverListener(event: any) {
      MOUSEX = event.x
      MOUSEY = event.y

      const deltaX = Math.abs(MOUSEX - LAST_POS[0])
      const deltaY = Math.abs(MOUSEY - LAST_POS[1])
      if (deltaX >= DELTA || deltaY >= DELTA) {
        LAST_POS = [MOUSEX, MOUSEY]
        for (const e in Movable.graph.edges) {
          Movable.graph.edges[e].resetCurrDefaults()
        }

        for (const i in Movable.graph.tables) {
          const xDiff = Math.abs(Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[0] - MOUSEX)
          const yDiff = Math.abs(Movable.graph.tables[i].currPos[1] - MOUSEY)

          if (
            xDiff < Movable.graph.bufferZone &&
            yDiff < Movable.graph.bufferZone
          ) {
            // check if was hovering in previous state
            // if true, then change nothing and break the loop
            if (Movable.graph.isHovering) {
              break
            }
            Movable.graph.isHovering = true

            Movable.graph.tables[i].highlight()
            //console.log(Movable.graph.tables[i]);

            break
          } else {
            //Movable.graph.tables[i].resetDefaults();
            Movable.graph.isHovering = false
          }
        }
        Movable.c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerWidth)
        Movable.graph.drawCanvas()
      }
    }
  },
  setup(props) {
    const canvasRef = ref()
    HEIGHT = window.innerHeight - 10
    WIDTH = window.innerWidth
    const { tableData, decodeHtmlEntities, getVariableNameById } = GetDataDic()
    tableData()

    const handleClick = (variable: Variable) => {
      moreInfoModal.value = true
      singleVariable.value = variable
    }
    const showVariableModal = (modal: boolean) => {
      variableModal.value = modal
    }

    const showMoreInfoModal = (modal: boolean) => {
      moreInfoModal.value = modal
    }

    watch(
      () => [props.jsonData.length, props.allEdges.length],
      () => {
        //Movable.c = ctx;
        Graph.allEdges = props.allEdges
        Movable.graph = new Graph(props.jsonData)
        //ctx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        //console.log(graph.topic);
        Movable.graph.drawCanvas()
      }
    )

    onMounted(() => {
      Movable.c = canvasRef.value.getContext("2d")
    })

    return {
      canvasRef,
      HEIGHT,
      WIDTH,
      isModalOpen,
      decodeHtmlEntities,
      getVariableNameById,
      showVariableModal,
      showMoreInfoModal,
      confirm,
      variableModal,
      moreInfoModal,
      singleTableData,
      singleVariable,
      tblName,
      handleClick
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It is possible, i suspect is has something to do with your variables and them overlapping or not updating correctly, an example of [canvas mouse down and move](https://codepen.io/reiallenramos/pen/MWaEmpw) working.

Comment: Your code is not *runnable*. And I don't even mean it in the sense: *"you should have spent the time to make a runnable snippet out of curtesy for people willing to help you"*. I mean it as in *"It can't be made runnable, no matter how much effort someone puts into it, because nobody (except yourself) knows what those imports contain"*. If you need help, spend time to create a ***runnable*** [mcve]. And ***do*** make it minimal. Remove ***as much stuff as you can*** from it until there's nothing else to remove and the bug is still reproducible.